# I need help reading request logs with ASP.NET 4.7.2 in BigQuery

Tags: c#, .net, google-bigquery

I want to read request logs from my controllers with BigQuery, can you give me the path on how I can do this? If you have some examples, you can also send in the answers. Grateful

I'm still just studying, but I can't find many things in the BigQuery API documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading request logs from ASP.NET controllers in BigQuery involves several steps:

**1. Logging Requests in ASP.NET:**

First, ensure that you are logging request data from your ASP.NET controllers.

```
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {
        // Log request data
        var logData = new
        {
            RequestUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
            RequestMethod = Request.HttpMethod,
            UserAgent = Request.UserAgent,
            // Add any other necessary data you want to log
        };

        LogRequest(logData);

        // Your action logic here...

        return View();
    }

    private void LogRequest(object logData)
    {
        // Your logic to log the data, e.g., write to a database, send to a service, etc.
    }
```

**2. Storing Logs:**

There are multiple ways to store logs. For our example, let's consider you are writing them to a SQL database. However, you can also consider using tools like Serilog, NLog, or Log4Net to manage logs.

**3. Exporting Logs to BigQuery:**

Once you have your logs stored, you can periodically export them to BigQuery for analysis. Here are the steps:

Export logs from your SQL database to a CSV or JSON file.
Use the BigQuery API or Console to upload this file to a BigQuery table.

**4. Querying with BigQuery:**

Once your data is in BigQuery, you can run SQL-like queries on it.

Example query:

```
SELECT RequestMethod, COUNT(*) as requestCount
FROM your_dataset.your_table
GROUP BY RequestMethod;
```

**5. Using BigQuery API with C#:**

You can also interact with BigQuery directly from your C# application using the Google Cloud libraries for .NET.

Install the necessary NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2
```

Use the library in your code:

```
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;

public void QueryBigQuery()
{
    var projectId = "your-project-id";
    var datasetName = "your_dataset";
    var tableName = "your_table";

    BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
    BigQueryTable table = client.GetTable(datasetName, tableName);

    string sql = @"SELECT RequestMethod, COUNT(*) as requestCount
                   FROM `your_dataset.your_table`
                   GROUP BY RequestMethod";

    BigQueryResults results = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters: null);

    foreach (var row in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{row["requestMethod"]}: {row["requestCount"]}");
    }
}
```